# Powershell MySql Assembly Reference

Tags: mysql, database, powershell, scripting

I am trying to connect to a MySql DB using powershell. 
I have the MySql .NET Connector.

Before running

```
[void][system.reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files\MySQL.Data.dll")
```

or

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")
```

I changed into the relative directory `c:/Program Files`

It just won't load, it does nothing. I'm not sure where to go from here or how to trouble shoot.

I am new to PowerShell, any advice / help is appreciated.

Comment: What are u trying to do ? What do you mean by it does nothing ? Are you trying to use the types from that assembly ? If so, take a look at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richardb/2007/02/21/add-types-ps1-poor-mans-using-for-powershell/

Comment: I'll take a look now. I mean when I run the command I don't get an eror but I also don't get any feed back. there's no output. I'm just trying to pull a table and read the data to start.

Comment: It's because you voided the return type. Try [system.reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files\MySQL.Data.dll") (without [void])

Comment: @ Prageeth Saravanan Ah, thanks I'm at least getting and exception now. It looks like the assembly is a newer runtime than the currently loaded runtime

Comment: hmm... I guess you know you will have to update your run time in that case. Glad it helped!

Comment: Yep got me in the right direction,  thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade PowerShell to PowerShell 4+
That features is not available in PowerShell 2
Nothing is wrong with the code.